# How to compile QOCI in QGIS master?

Tags: qgis, oracle-dbms, linux

I am trying to compile QOCI in QGIS master, I followed the instructions, directly from QT, but I still get the same error: "fatal error: QtSql / private / qsqlcachedresult_p.h".
I am working on a 32 bit machine, linux Xenial and with the instant client of oracle version 12.2,

How can I fix the error?

[image]

Comment: Well ... the error is obvious: it cannot find file "QtSql/private/qsqlcachedresult_p.h". Did you verify that this file actually exists ? Perhaps with a different filespec ? Did you try finding it using "find" ? It looks like a part of the QtSql module. Is that installed ? How does the QOCI build find it ?